# How can I disable my Multmedia key on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, script, autohotkey

I got a new keyboard and I want to disable the button that opens a music window. I tried to disable it or change it with autohotkey but then it just launches the music player anyways and does what I told it to.
Look at this Key history after pressing that music player button:

```
B5  16D a   d   1.34    Launch_Media    
A4  038 a   d   0.00    LAlt            
A4  038 a   u   0.00    LAlt            
A4  038 a   d   0.00    LAlt            
A4  038 a   u   0.00    LAlt            
B5  16D a   u   0.09    Launch_Media    Groove-Musik
```

Comment: Doesn't the software that came with your keyboard allow you to modify these keys?

Comment: @DavidPostill not the multimedia keys sadly

Comment: So when you say you tried to disable it in AutoHotkey, does that mean you have an AutoHotkey script running (as visible with a little tray icon), with a line in the running script that says `Launch_Media::Return`, and pressing the media key still results in the media player being launched?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this method, by tampering with the registry,
and here are the steps:

1. Run registry editor (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type `regedit` and `enter`)
2. Browse down to the following key:

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
3. Right click and add a value  (`REG_BINARY`) name it `Scancode Map`
4. Add this data and be carefull:

   > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 6D E0 00 00 00 00
5. Save and reboot.

some usefull links :
[Keyboard and mouse class drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers)
[ScanCodes of Special keyboards](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-6.html)